# why i can't read simple xml file from my service process?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have simple service that i wrote in .net 4.5
I install it on my machine and its run.

When my service start i go to some folder on my disk (C:/ServiceFolder) that contain simple xml file that hold my service configuration - and i trying to load it.

i getting UnauthorizedAccessException. 
When i take the xml file and i copy it to c:/windows/system32 folder - i get FileNotFoundException even when the file exist.

So, what i did wrong ?
How to solve this issue ?

Comment: How did you install the service? Looks like what ever the user account that  the service is running on, does not have necessary privileges to access a file in a system folder.

Comment: yes, i install the service. this is simple machine that does not have any special  privileges as far as i know.
maybe some other way is possible ?

Comment: Easiest way to know is build a small command line exe with a similar code to your service and run it and see if it can access the file.

Comment: my code is simple. i try to access file as you said - not success

Comment: Code can be simple. But it's clear you are having a permission issue. Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` folder (%AppData%) instead of the folder that you are trying to use.